# map and filter function on array of lists

Tags: python, mapping

I want to map an array of lists like the one below using the function `process_slide_index(x)`

**tiles_index:**

```
[(1, 1024, 0, 16, 0, 0), (1, 1024, 0, 16, 0, 1), (1, 1024, 0, 16, 0, 2), (1, 1024, 0, 16, 0, 3), (1, 1024, 0, 16, 0, 4), (1, 1024, 0, 16, 0, 5), (1, 1024, 0, 16, 0, 6),...]
```

**tiles:**

```
tiles = map(lambda x: process_slide_index(x), tiles_index)
```

**the map function:**

```
def process_slide_index(tile_index):
    print("PROCESS SLIDE INDEX")
    slide_num, tile_size, overlap, zoom_level, col, row = tile_index
    slide = open_slide(slide_num)
    generator = create_tile_generator(slide, tile_size, overlap)
    tile = np.asarray(generator.get_tile(zoom_level, (col, row)))

    return (slide_num, tile)
```

I'm applying the map function but I don't seem to get inside my `process_slide_index(tile_index)` function.

I also want to filter some results given a function that returns `True` of `False`. But once again my function does not reach the filter function.

```
filtered_tiles = filter(lambda x: keep_tile(x, tile_size, tissue_threshold), tiles)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

**EDIT** The only way I got to reach that checkpoint message `PROCESS SLIDE INDEX` was adding `list(map(print, tiles))` after the **tiles** line. I was using this to try to debug and my prints started showing up. I'm pretty confused right now.

Comment: changing `map(lambda x: process_slide_index(x), tiles_index)` to `list(map(lambda x: process_slide_index(x), tiles_index))` did the trick. Does this makes sense?

Comment: BTW, instead of `lambda x: process_slide_index(x)`, just `process_slide_index` suffices.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `python3`, in **python2** `map` and `filter` return a list, but in **python3** they return an object that you have to consume to get the values:

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> def foo(x):
...     print(x)
...     return x+1
... 
>>> map(foo, l)
<map object at 0x7f69728da828>
```

For consuming this object, you can use `list` for example. Notice how the `print` is called this time:

```
>>> list(map(foo, l))
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

This objects are lazy, that means that they `yield` the values one by one. Check the differences when using them as iterators in a `for` loop:

```
>>> for e in map(foo, l):
...     print(e)
... 
0
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
9
10
```

Using `list` does the same, but stores each taken value in that list.

Comment: read my post comment. I guess it complements your answer. Or maybe not.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going test with `tiles = list(map(lambda x: process_slide_index(x), tiles_index))`

Comment: Use a list comprehension instead. It'll make your life so much easier and your code so much faster than those lambdas.

Comment: @geofurb, Even if you are correct, you are making a lot assumptions there. In this case, the usage would go for `generators` if he wants to split the computation in 2. Anyway, the question referred to `map` and `filter` so comprehensions should be discussed in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the lambda from your `map` call. `map` will call the function provided in the first argument and in your case you have provided a wrapper function for the function you actually want to call.

```
tiles = map(process_slide_index, tiles_index)
```

Comment: What about then I want to pass additional parameters on my function? For example on my  `filtered_tiles = filter(lambda x: keep_tile(x, tile_size, tissue_threshold), tiles)`, x is the object from tiles and then `tile_size`and `tile_threshold`

Comment: It can be easier (and I have heard more efficient, too) to just use list comprehension in that case: `filtered_tiles = [x for x in tiles if keep_tile(x, tile_size, tissue_threshold)]`

Comment: Thank you very much then. Going to test it.
I know it is out of topic, but do you have any idea how can I flatter a list of arrays? Something like `samples = filtered_tiles.flatMap(lambda tile: process_tile(tile, sample_size, grayscale))`

Comment: It would probably be helpful to give an example of what you want to end up with, and probably as a new question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But about what you suggested. Imagine I have something like `samples = list(map(lambda x: process_tile(x, sample_size, grayscale), filtered_tiles))`. It is possible to still use your approach?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR -**

- List comprehension can do a lot of things you might want here. `[x for x in mylist if x > y]` is a powerful expression that more than replaces `filter()`. It's also a nice alternative to `map()`, and is *much* more efficient than using a lambda expression. It also spits out a list instead of a generator, which is probably preferable in your case. (If you're dealing with *huge* streams of data, you might want to stick with `map` and `filter`, because with generators you don't have to keep the whole thing in RAM, you can work out one value at a time.) If you like this suggestion and want to skip the talk, I give you the code in **2b**.
- Don't write a lambda expression for a function that already exists! Lambda expressions are stand-in functions where you haven't defined one. They're *much* slower and have some weird behaviors. Avoid them where possible. You could replace the lambda in your `map()` call with the function itself: `tiles = map(process_slide_index, tiles_index)`

**The long version:**

There are two problems, both are pretty easy to fix. First one is more of a style/efficiency thing, but it'll save you some obscure headaches, too:

**1.** Instead of creating a lambda expression, it's best to use the function you already went to the work of defining!
`tiles = map(process_slide_index, tiles_index)` does the job just fine, and behaves better.

**2.** You should probably switch to list comprehensions. Why? Because `map()` and `filter()` are uglier and they're slower if you have to use a lambda or want to convert the output to a list afterwards. Still, if you insist on using `map()` and `filter()`...

**2a.** When you need to pass multiple arguments into a function for map, try `functools.partial` if you know many of the values ahead of time. I think it's an error in your logic when you're trying
`filtered_tiles = filter(lambda x: keep_tile(x, tile_size, tissue_threshold), tiles)`
What you're telling it to do is to call `keep_tile()` on a vector of `[x for x in tiles]` while holding `tile_size` and `tissue_threshold` constant.

If this is the intended behavior, try `import functools` and use `functools.partial(keep_tile, tile_size, tissue_threshold)`.
Note: Using `functools.partial` requires that any variables you pass to the partial function are the rightmost arguments, so you'd have to rewrite the function header as `def keep_tile(tile_size, tissue_threshold, tiles):` instead of `def keep_tile(tiles, tile_size, tissue_threshold):`. (See that we again manage to avoid a lambda expression!)

If that *isn't* the intended behavior, and you wanted each of those values to change with every call, just pass a tuple in! `filter(keep_tile, (tile, tile_size, tissue_threshold)))`. If you just want the `tile` variable from this, you can use a list comprehension:
`[x[0] for x in filter(keep_tile, (tile, tile_size, tissue_threshold)))]` (Again, with no lambdas.) However, since we're already doing a list comprehension here, you might want to try the solution in **2b.**

**2b.** It's generally faster and cleaner on later Python releases just to use a list comprehension such as `[x[0] for x in tiles if keep_tile(*x)]`. (Or, if you meant to hold the other two values constant, you could use `[x for x in tiles if keep_tile(x, tile_size, tissue_threshold)]`.) Any time you're just going to read that `map()` or `filter()`'s output into a list afterwards, you should probably have used a list comprehension instead. At this point `map()` and `filter()` are really only useful for streaming results through a pipeline, or for async routines.